# Node Server hanging while running react native app

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to learn React Native. I created a sample application which worked fine before, but suddenly it is hanging when I'm running it using ***react-native run-android***. I'm getting a loading message Bundling `index.android.js`  [development, non-minified, hmr disabled]  ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░  0.0% (0/4) which is keep on showing without any progress improvement and I've no clue on what to do next. Kindly assist.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';


import TabView from './tabView';

export default class TabsProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
  
<TabView/>
 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you try running `react-native start` before running it on android

Comment: Facing the same issue while doing react-native start

Answer (score 0):

Cancel your current runnign packager and try running the following commands to see if it helps.

`adb kill-server
adb start-server
watchman watch-del-all
npm start -- --reset-cache`